# Can an RNA anneal to its complementary (not reverse) sequence?

Tags: biochemistry, rna

Say I have a target RNA strand:

5'--AAUGGCCCUUUAAA-->3'

I know that this strand will readily anneal to the sequence

3'<--UUACCGGGAAAUUU--5'

which is the reverse-complement. I'm wondering if this strand will also anneal to it's "forward" complement, namely:

5'--UUACCGGGAAAUUU-->3'

?

In other words, can RNA form parallel helix structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is DNA antiparallel? Can it be parallel?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27839/why-is-dna-antiparallel-can-it-be-parallel)

Answer (score -1):

No. The 5' end has to anneal to the 3' end of the other strand. Here your 5' end is AAU and the 3' UUU, so you can see that U will not pair with U.

Comment: It is, of course, a matter of opinion, but my opinion is that if this question can be answered in two lines it is a poor question for which the poster shows no evidence of having done any research himself. (It may even be a homework question.) I would say that this comes under the category of [questions that should be ignored](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and the poster encouraged to do some [research of his own](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as this site requires.

Comment: @charlesdarwin why is that?

Comment: @mike-flynn, I don't really understand your comment. In a double-stranded DNA helix, if you move along the helix, one strand goes in the 5'-3' direction and the other strands goes in the 3'-5' direction. So, if you want to pair 5'--AAUGGCCCUUUAAA-->3' and 5'--UUACCGGGAAAUUU-->3' you have to flip one over, align them and check that all nucleotides are complementary. When you flip over 5'--UUACCGGGAAAUUU-->3'  you get 3'-UUU...5' and you can stop here because you see that the third U does not match the U in 5'--AAUGGCCCUUUAAA-->3'.

Comment: @charlesdarwin, I'm talking about paring *without* flipping them over. Taking two free floating RNA strands that are complementary *only* in parallel direction (5' to 3'), will they form a helix. Can helices form with 5' ends going together towards 3' ends - or why not? That is my question. I **don't think** you have to "flip" them over as you say, I don't think that's chemically necessary.

Comment: @mike-flynn I think they do need to be parallel to pair up.